# Is Android location apis' full-proof?

Tags: android, gps

I had a strange encounter once: The location on the phone's map application and even my application was wrong by a very large delta. As in it was quite off the actual location. Is it something many have encountered or some bug with my device ? What is the approx probability of this happening (from those who have tested this bug) ?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy SII with ICS and my application fetches info from GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: The reason it is so hard to make things `foolproof` is because fools are so ingenious.

Comment: oops...my bad, nevertheless the question does make sense doesnt it ? ;)

Comment: Your question is fine, I just like that quote about foolproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have an encountered a cached location if the maps application couldn't get a fix on your current location. For getting up to date locations in you app take a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898930/how-to-get-location-that-isnt-out-of-date)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty normal for my location to be off by a large amount for a few seconds after a device turns on, until the radios can get a fix.

Comment: Is there any kind of parameter we can check to verify if the device radios have a fix or not ? I check my location on a timer or location updated event whichever is earlier.

Comment: You can use a GpsStatusListener to check for a few events including the first fix, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9768664/1127492

Comment: Thanks stefan, I will add this Listener.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen errors of more than 10000 km.  I was looking at `network` fixes which come from cells and wifi only, no gps.  The fix put me in England (UK) somewhere even though I was at an outlet mall in California (US).  My guess is that someone had moved their wifi server from England to California and the Google WiFi database had not updated itself yet.  I had a few more errors like that but not as spectacular, only 1000-5000 km reporting locations in other states of the US.

Network fixes based on cell towers will usually be 1 km off and are often 10 km off.  These are based on the cell tower seen by the phone, and in hilly terrain you can often miss the closest cell tower and grab one that is on a high location a few km away.

GPS fixes also can have errors, but usually less than 1 km.  These errors mostly come when some GPS signals are blocked by hills or buildings or reflected off nearby hills or buildings.

I have seen all of the above when testing Android phone positioning.  Not all phones will behave identically, the quality of the GPS implementation (chip choice, rf design) can make big differences in performance.

Comment: That is exactly what I faced. I was testing in India and it showed my position somewhere near Vietnam. A totally baffling moment. Thanks for sharing your experience, I am not alone !!