# LocationManager with 3G only works after reboot

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have an application that retrieves the location of the provider's network, the problem is that the site isn't being recovered (not happening in `onLocationChange`) when using 3G or WI-Fi.

Does anyone know what can be? After reboot the device works normally.

Here is my code:

```
locationManager = getSystemService (LocationManager) (LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, this);
```

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747543/locationlistener-of-network-provider-is-enabled-but-onlocationchanged-is-never

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: I'm using the S2, S3, Galaxy Tab, Galaxy Note, Galaxy Y.

Comment: If you restart the device works. Strange that this did not occur, the only thing I remember was a change in the application refactor the package.

Comment: Could you be able to fix this problem. Can you tell us how? thnks