# My onLocationChanged never triggers

Tags: android, gps, location

have found no complete guide on how to implement this. I have:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //My location changed
            myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLatitude());
            date = new Date();

            //Update marker
            myMarker.snippet(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString());
            myMarker.position(myPosition);

            //Update map
            //updateMap();

            //Move camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
            //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

            //Show dialog
            boxUpdate.show();

            Log.i("Map Location", "New cache for location retrived!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            //Required, but not in use
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            //Required, but not in use
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            //Required, but not in use
        }
    });
```

So, what do I need to do to make it work?
I have only WiFi enabled, but I think the cache is completly empty and wont fill up somehow. Am I missing something essential to make it listen at all?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get location using your wifi then change this..

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener()
```

to

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener()
```

let me know if still not work.

SO force with you:)

Comment: I had that first, that didn't really work either. But I'll give it another try. May have been another cause earlier...
I'll repost in 10min tops

Comment: Doesn't seem like it does anything yet. I can see that it may be a required change still though. Any more guesses?

Comment: some times you may need to restart your device to work this providers properly..see this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/q/15747543/1199602 looks like same issue as you have

Comment: Hmm, still nothing =/

Comment: if you are using `gps` then give it sometime. It may take about 20 minutes some times. For testing you can use `network` to detect location since it is fast and use log for `gps`. Also have you added necessary permissions in `androidmanifest.xml`. Also i must ask, are you referring of switching on wifi of `Settings>Wireless & Networks` or `Settings> Locations & Security>Use Wireless Networks`? Since the second option detect the location.