# NoClassDefFoundError after AndroidStudio upgrade to 1.0 (December 8th)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

with previous versions of Android Studio working properly with Release Candidate 4 (December 4th) or newer:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient
```

it seems to me that it is related to update `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 '`

This looks similar:
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1136

Edit

working : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

Comment: What is in your XML file?

Comment: check my topic again

Comment: This isn't XML. Your NoClassDefFound may have nothing to do with how you build, since it's in runtime. Do you have an XML where you define fragments and everything?

Comment: all files XML are correct, I changed nothing in the project, only updated the Android Studio, with an older version of Android studio working properly, i changed only `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` because Android Studio forced me to change

Comment: Did you try clean and rebuild?

Comment: of course and all the tricks on the web, when i bulid project with old verssion Android Studio then working with out problems

Comment: I still think there's something wrong in your manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with gradle. It's an update for Google Play Services. The `LocationClient` class has been replaced with the new `FusedLocationProviderApi`.

Check this answer:
[Android play services 6.5: LocationClient is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372638/android-play-services-6-5-locationclient-is-missing)

Comment: working : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this :**

```
dependencies 
{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.9.+'
}
```

**And also do**

```
    buildTypes 
   {
        release 
       {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.txt'
        }
    }
```