# Gradle does not find my online dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to convert my projects from eclipse to android studio... And I already fail with my simpliest project.

I always get errors like following:

> Error:Failed to find: com.nispok:snackbar:2.5.2
>
> Error:Failed to find: com.github.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter:multichoiceadapter-abc:3.0.0
>
> Error:Failed to find: com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2

Actually, NO online resource is found at all... I checked Gradle settings and checked, that Offline work is not checked.

What can I do next?

**I have following two files:**

My PROJECT gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

My LIBRARIES gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':newQuickAction3D')

    compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter:multichoiceadapter-abc:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you working behind a proxy? Because in this case you would have to configure the proxy settings for your Android Studio

Comment: In the IDE settings (under HTTP Proxy settings) I've configured my proxy... And first start of android studio did work as well with my settings... Is there another place to configure the proxy? Checking connection in the HTTP Proxy settings does succeed as well...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link..Do ReConfigure Gradle settings.. may be fruitful for you..
[NoClassDefFoundError after AndroidStudio upgrade to 1.0 (December 8th)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418198/noclassdeffounderror-after-androidstudio-upgrade-to-1-0-december-8th/27418484#27418484)

Comment: try it.. and give your feedback @prom85

Comment: this gave me some error like: Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: but with this I found following: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61274 and the #13 comment helped... Gradle needs the proxy settings added as VW Args and can't use the one from android studio...