# The import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, location

I am making an android application that uses Google maps. I had the code working perfectly until I upgraded Eclipse from Juno to Luna. I also updated some revisions of the SDK that were published. After this, a lot bunch of errors appeared in my code (whose was working nicely before, maybe from the Eclipse update). After repairing the errors and re-importing the libraries, one error remains "`The import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient cannot be resolved`". After some searches online I found that the "`google-play-services_lib`" is needed to be imported again and by the error log it isn't found. I checked in the buildpath and properties of my project and the library and folder were present. I deleted them and re-imported again just to be sure, but the problem persists.

[image: Build Path]

[image: Library view]

[image: Project Folder]

What I don' understand is how it is possible that the same code worked and now it doesn't. I have even downloaded the Android Studio, downloaded the Google Play Services from there to a new location, imported it and still the same. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check the link, it may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372638/android-play-services-
6-5-locationclient-is-missing

Comment: That guy asked it 4 days before me :). Anyway it is a solved problem thanks to @purplemind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure did you check box ***Is Library***: at workspace right click on google-play-services_lib -> Properties -> Android?

Comment: Is there class LocationClient within google-play-services_lib com.google.android.gms.location package? If there is not, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation)

Comment: The class wasn't present. I followed the indications in the link and the error has disappeared. Now I cannot open the map because it doesn't recognize the api key (I'm on a different PC), but I believe it will work.

Comment: Window->Preferences->Android->Build: check if following settings "Default debug keystore", "MD5", "SHA1" are correct. Or set API key again via google console following [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api)

Answer (score 0):

In Project Properties->JavaBuildPath section-> order and Export section.
Make sure checkbox is checked or not for googlePlayService. 
And then clean your project and re-build.

Comment: It was unchecked. I checked it, clean-build and still the same.

Comment: You will need the Google Play Services SDK configured within Eclipse and import google play services as library will dismiss this error. Make sure Google Play Services SDK is configured within your Eclipse.

Comment: What do you mean with "Google Play Services SDK configured within Eclipse"? The project is imported through Eclipse, imported as Library. Anything else?

Comment: Try to import as library.

Comment: If you check the screenshots it is already imported. I have also imported the google-play-service_lib.jar as external source checked in Order and Export and still nothing.