# The import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient cannot be resolved after formatting computer

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-appcompat, r.java-file, location-client

I formatted my computer and again imported my android project which has been done using Google Maps API V2 and found out many errors.I re-linked google_play_services_lib and android-support-v7-appcompat.I still find an error in importing com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.Only the call of "LocationClient" gives an error and others are imported fine.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
(ERROR)import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

and find errors everywhere I have used R. calling.
error :  R cannot be resolved to a variable

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

and getting the following errors in the console.

```
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] 
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject] C:\Users\Sudesh\Android_Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-19 23:22:44 - MapsProject]
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27372638/1676363) for how to switch your application to FusedLocationProviderApi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`LocationClient` was deprecated a while ago and apparently was removed from Play Services recently. You will need to switch to using `GoogleApiClient` to get the `LocationServices.API`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/FusedNew) demonstrates how to do this. Basically:

Step #1: Set up a `GoogleApiClient` data member of whatever is using the API:

```
private GoogleApiClient client=null;
```

Step #2: Request the `LocationServices.API`:

```
client=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(host)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

Step #3: In `onConnected()` of your `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, start using
`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi` to work with locations (e.g., call `getLastLocation()`)

Comment: what's with the errors in                     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                         EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);                                                 R Cannot Be resolved to a variable

Comment: @SNT93: You appear to be using `appcompat-v7`, and so you need to set your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android) to API Level 21 or higher. That has nothing to do with `LocationClient`.

Comment: @SNT93: I would recommend that you look at the sample project that I linked to in my answer. There is also [this blog post](http://davistechyinfo.blogspot.com/2014/09/android-location-updates-with.html) and various other Stack Overflow answers [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25173057/115145). Unfortunately, Google has not documented this stuff yet, so I cannot point you at docs.

Comment: How can I start a map using GoogleAPIClient Previously i used        if(initMap())
{mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);   mLocationClient.connect();}                                  else
{
Toast.makeText(this,"Map Not Available!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Comment: @SNT93: That code does not start a map. You would do much the same thing here, just with the `GoogleApiClient` stuff in your `if` block.

Comment: Have I done right ?                                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579591/runtime-errors-while-launching-the-map

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the google play library in the same folder? I mean when importing there is an option copy project to the existing workspace. Check it when importing.  [image]

Comment: yes I did that.Both the references are having green ticks

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client:

> When you want to make a connection to one of the Google APIs provided
>   in the Google Play services library (such as Google+, Games, or
>   Drive), you need to create an instance of GoogleApiClient ("Google API
>   Client"). The Google API Client provides a common entry point to all
>   the Google Play services and manages the network connection between
>   the user's device and each Google service.