# android studio cannot resilve symbol LocationClient

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, location-client

I'm working with AndroidStudio and trying to use the googleplayservices for geocode.

I've followed the android tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

but in my imports i've got underlined :
import android.location.**LocationClient**;
that says: Cannot resolve symbol Location Client

Any ideas?

My code goes as next:

```
//imports
...
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import android.location.LocationClient;
...
```

build.grandle

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
...
```

and finally my xml manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.name.application_name" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    ....
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <activity
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `LocationClient` in package [`android.location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html).  This is why your import is resulting in an error.

In fact, the `LocationClient` class is deprecated.  From [Google Play Services | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html):

> Deprecated clients - The `ActivityRecognitionClient`, **`LocationClient`**, and `PlusClient` classes are deprecated. If you used those APIs in your app and want to call Google Play services 6.5 or higher APIs, you must switch to the new programming model that utilizes [`GoogleApiClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html). For more information about using [`GoogleApiClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html), see [Accessing Google APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html).
>
> Use these APIs instead of the deprecated APIs:
>
> ...If you were previously using `LocationClient`, call the APIs in the [`com.google.android.gms.location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html) package instead.

For quick information on migrating from `LocationClient` to [`GoogleApiClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html), see [android - LocationClient class not found on google play services rev 22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27372864/4572596)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that `LocationClient` was deprecated... I'll read more about..

Answer (score 0):

Add google play services older version in your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```