# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient Error while using Vungle sdk

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, vungle-ads

My app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mss.jackpotslots"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    //====================Add below two line=============
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
       // compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-3.2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    compile project(':wheelLib')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project Level Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
      //  classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My LogCat Error OutPut

```
 E/VungleAsync: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.location.GooglePlayServicesDetailedLocationProvider.a(vungle:30)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.location.AndroidLocation.b(vungle:35)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestAd$Demographic$Location$Factory.b(vungle:180)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestAd$Demographic$Factory.b(vungle:130)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestAd$a.b(vungle:84)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestLocalAd$Factory.c(vungle:71)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.RequestLocalAdHttpRequest$Factory.d(vungle:68)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.inject.ConfigurablePublisherModule.a(vungle:325)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.inject.ConfigurablePublisherModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideRequestLocalAdHttpTransactionProvidesAdapter.get(vungle:849)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.inject.ConfigurablePublisherModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideRequestLocalAdHttpTransactionProvidesAdapter.get(vungle:810)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.ProtocolHttpGateway$2.run(vungle:127)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.async.ScheduledPriorityExecutor$a$a.run(vungle:233)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

> I am facing this error while i am running my app .i dont know why this
>   is showing this issue if any one have done this before please help
>   thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to update Google Play Service SDK and then use updated library.

Answer (score 0):

New (ever since Google released [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)) releases of `com.google.android.gms.location` do not contain the class named `LocationClient`. Instead, now we use a centralized API services implementation - the [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) class. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27372864/2150044) for info on how to update your logic accordingly.

For the list of interfaces and classes in the newest `com.google.android.gms.location` package visit this link: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary

Comment: i am not using Location class it is coming because of vungle jar and i can not remove that

Comment: I understand, but that is the problem. If they have stopped supporting that library and didn't update their dependencies you won't be able to use that .jar

Comment: i am also getting this issue "Error:Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.fyber.annotations.processor.MediationAnnotationProcessor could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/squareup/javapoet/TypeName"   can you give me any hint

Answer (score 0):

```
 E/VungleAsync: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.location.GooglePlayServicesDetailedLocationProvider.a(vungle:30)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.location.AndroidLocation.b(vungle:35)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestAd$Demographic$Location$Factory.b(vungle:180)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestAd$Demographic$Factory.b(vungle:130)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestAd$a.b(vungle:84)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.message.RequestLocalAd$Factory.c(vungle:71)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.RequestLocalAdHttpRequest$Factory.d(vungle:68)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.inject.ConfigurablePublisherModule.a(vungle:325)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.inject.ConfigurablePublisherModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideRequestLocalAdHttpTransactionProvidesAdapter.get(vungle:849)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.inject.ConfigurablePublisherModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideRequestLocalAdHttpTransactionProvidesAdapter.get(vungle:810)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.protocol.ProtocolHttpGateway$2.run(vungle:127)
                                                                       at com.vungle.publisher.async.ScheduledPriorityExecutor$a$a.run(vungle:233)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.
I am Aki from Vungle.

Can you try to use our latest Android SDK? 
https://v.vungle.com/dashboard/api/1/sdk/android

If you still see the issue, please contact tech-support@vungle.com.

Thanks,
-aki